# Use nexus 7(2013 wifi) from laptop

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, nexus-7

I have been mucking around with the chrome developer tools and have seen a way to see what happens in a tab on your table on your laptop. I was wondering if there was a way to completely control and see what is happening on a nexus 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is, but not through chrome. You can use **myMobiler** (http://goo.gl/0KDQTX) or **teamViewer** (http://goo.gl/0JZFVE). You can control with them on your Android device (from your computer) or the other way around.

There is another way, with **Chrome Remote Desktop** (http://goo.gl/Ia53bi) but you can control only your computer right now (there is an android app) but I believe that there will be an update (in the future) so we can control our Android phone.

I know it's not exactly what you meant, but what you meant currently does not exist. Anyway, hope this helps..